# How to test autocomplete using phpunit selenium2

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I'd like to make a test with an autocomplete [Jquery](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) field, I can't access the hidden field attached to it.

I searched on Google, without success :(

Do you have any examples for testing that ?

Below, our test code:

```
function testTest(){
    $this->url("/");
    $input = $this->byLinkText("Développement / programmation");
    $input->click();

    $input = $this->byId("js_header_autocomplete_activity");
    $input->clear();
    $input->value("Développement / programmation");
}
```

I was able to do it with phpunit selenium 1 but it's now deprecated.

Any solutions ?

Regards,
William